# How to filters across multiple tabs R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a R Shiny App that contains three tabs. I would like to display a filter on the first two tabs and no filter on the third tab. I would like the filter on tabs one and two to be synchronized.

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   dataset <- reactive({
      get(input$dataset, "package:datasets")
   })
   
   output$summary <- renderPrint({
      summary(dataset())
   })
   
   output$table <- renderTable({
      dataset()
   })
   
   output$table_head <- renderTable({
      head(dataset())
   })
}


ui <- fluidPage(

   tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
               tabPanel(title = "tab one filtered",
                        sidebarLayout(
                           sidebarPanel(
                              selectInput("dataset", label = "filter", choices = ls("package:datasets"))
                              ),
                           mainPanel(
                           verbatimTextOutput("summary")
                           )
                        )
                     ),
               tabPanel(title = "tab two filtered",
                        sidebarLayout(
                           sidebarPanel(
                              selectInput("dataset", label = "filter", choices = ls("package:datasets"))
                              ),
                        mainPanel(
                           tableOutput("table")
                           )
                        )
                     ),
               tabPanel(title = "tab three unfiltered",
                        mainPanel(
                           tableOutput("table_head")
                        )
                     )
            )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My code is very similar to this. When I run this, the filter on the second page does not work. How can I display a synchronized filter on the first two tabs and no filter on the third tab. I've seen the suggestion  to have the `selectInput` outside of the `tabsetPanel` but the filter will show on the third page. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two elements with the same ID in a given layout. So first you'll want to given them separate IDs

```
tabPanel(title = "tab one filtered",
         sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel(
             selectInput("dataset1", label = "filter", choices = ls("package:datasets"))
           ),
           mainPanel(
             verbatimTextOutput("summary")
           )
         )
),
tabPanel(title = "tab two filtered",
         sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel(
             selectInput("dataset2", label = "filter", choices = ls("package:datasets"))
           ),
           mainPanel(
             tableOutput("table")
           )
         )
),
```

then you'll need to do some extra work in the server to keep them insync.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  datasetname <- reactiveVal(ls("package:datasets")[1])

  observeEvent(input$dataset1, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "dataset2", selected=input$dataset1)
    datasetname(input$dataset1)
  })
  observeEvent(input$dataset2, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "dataset1", selected=input$dataset2)
    datasetname(input$dataset2)
  })
  
  
  dataset <- reactive({
    get(datasetname(), "package:datasets")
  })
  ...
}
```

We keep a separate reactive value `datasetname` to keep track of the active name. Then we update the UI when one of the two dataset1/dataset2 values changes.

Comment: This help me troubleshoot a related problem - apparently re-using _outputs_ also causes lots of unforeseen problems....